# What do the following words/phrases mean?

Tags: translation

I'm trying to understand [this article](https://www.topgear.com/car-news/concept/vision-mercedes-maybach-6-cabriolet-will-blow-your-mind) on the latest [Vision Mercedes-Maybach 6 Cabriolet](https://www.mercedes-benz.com/en/mercedes-benz/vehicles/passenger-cars/mercedes-maybach/revelation-of-luxury-vision-mercedes-maybach-6-cabriolet/) and there are some words/phrases I don't quite understand.

1. **Be still my beating wallet.**
2. Cartoonish proportions are backed up by headlights that are no more than slits, and **a grille Lady Penelope would be proud of**.
3. Unfortunately **it’s just a Vision for now**, but nothing about the technology is beyond the realms of possibility. **So**, let’s hope enough **well-heeled and well-lubricated punters** at Pebble Beach told Mercedes they wanted to buy one immediately
4. (Not included in the above webpage) Perfect for the French Riviera, not ideal in your local **NCP**

I've first looked them up in the dictionary and then I googled all of them.
Here is what I could come up with so far:

1. **Be still my beating wallet.** : Don't be upset with the price of the car.
2. The google search taught me Lady Penelope is is a fictional character in a British TV series in the mid-60s. I also found out that she drove [FAB 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAB_1), which has a front grille similar to the one we see in [the 6 cabriolet](https://www.mercedes-benz.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2017/08/01-mercedes-benz-vehicles-vision-mercedes-maybach-6-cabriolet-2560x1440-1280x720.jpg). So I took them to mean "even 
   Lady Penelope would approve of the front grille of the 6 cabriolet."
3. I suppose the word "Vision" means two things: the car itself (**Vision** Mercedes-Maybach 6 Cabriolet) and the future in which new versions of the car will be launched. I don't quite see the logical connection between the first sentence and the second one, so I'm not sure why the author uses **So** in this context. I understand **well-heeled and well-lubricated punters** to simply mean "rich people".
4. I suppose **NCP** is a bus company so I understand the above to mean "Not ideal for your local bus company", which doesn't quite make sense.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: "just a Vision for now" means that it hasn't yet been produced for sale--the model shown at Pebble Beach (top U.S. car show) is probably the only one that exists. So (meaning _thus_), it will be produced if enough people tell Mercedes they're willing to buy one.  (I don't know what NCP means--this seems to be British.)  Everything else I think you've got right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Be still my beating wallet* paraphrases - perhaps lampoons - *Be still my beating heart*, meaning roughly, *Wow! That sets my heart pounding but hey! Let’s try to stay calm about it*.

Having ridden in the real FAB 1 yes, I promise *a grille Lady Penelope would be proud of* means she’d not only approve of it, but might well aspire to having one.
 
In *just a Vision for now*, nothing would change if *So* was dropped but that the sentence would become the more readily understandible. *well-heeled and well-lubricated punters* does mean *rich people*.

In Britain, anyway, *NCP* stands for *National Car Parks*; hopefully self-evident. Does that make more sense?